# Android app crashes with setText in second Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, settext

my app should  show me in the second Activity a string that I generate with an editText in the first Activity after I press the button.

```
package com.example.josue.sw22;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button Siguiente;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText NUMERO = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etTelefono);
        Siguiente=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bSiguiente);

        Siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intento = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LucesAlarma.class);
                intento.putExtra("numero",NUMERO.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intento);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

**This is the second Activity:**

```
 package com.example.josue.sw22;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LucesAlarma extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView numactual;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_luces_alarma);

        numactual = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etTelefono);

        String numeropos;
        numeropos = getIntent().getExtras().getString("numero");
        numactual.setText(numeropos);

    }

}
```

After I use the button in the first activity, the app crashes, everything is OK in the getIntent part because when I don't use the setText line the app runs well.. PLease help!!!!!

Here are the layots:

**First Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.josue.sw20.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Inserte el numero del modulo"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etTelefono"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Siguiente"
        android:id="@+id/bSiguiente"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etTelefono"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Second Activity layout** (I dont use the buttons yet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.josue.sw22.LucesAlarma"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_luces_alarma">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:text="Prender Alarma"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:text="Apagar Alarma"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="............"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="............"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sensores"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Numero Actual"
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="77dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/tvNUMERO"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**My App Manifest**(I have a third activity, I am not using it yet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.josue.sw22">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LucesAlarma"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_luces_alarma"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.josue.sw22" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <activity
            android:name=".Sensores"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sensores"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.josue.sw22" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The exeption:

```
03-07 11:51:39.445 1412-1412/com.example.josue.sw22 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: com.example.josue.sw22, PID: 1412
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.josue.sw22/com.example.josue.sw22.LucesAlarma}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at com.example.josue.sw22.LucesAlarma.onCreate(LucesAlarma.java:41)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Android app crashes - > post logcat

Comment: Is your `etTelefono` belong to `activity_luces_alarma` layout ?

Comment: have you declare app in menifeast file?

Comment: Post your exception please

Comment: make sure `TextView` with id `R.id.etTelefono` present in `activity_luces_alarma` xml file..that may be the cause

Comment: Can you post your logcat output or layout file `activity_luces_alarma` ?

Comment: I have post the layouts, the manifest and the exeption

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here-

```
 numactual = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etTelefono);
```

**etTelefono** is the ID of Edittext, which you are referencing as Textview.

Answer (score 2):

just make this change in your manifest file:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".LucesAlarma"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_luces_alarma"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.josue.sw22" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter></activity>//close your actvity here
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

you miss this `Intent intent = getIntent()` in your second activity

```
public class LucesAlarma extends AppCompatActivity {

public TextView numactual;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_luces_alarma);

    numactual = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etTelefono);

   Intent intent = getIntent();
   String numeropos =intent.getStringExtra("numero");
   numactual.setText(numeropos);
  }
 }
```

Comment: the problem remains the same, I believe that there is no diference between your code and mine, if i am wrong please, let me now, i think the problem is in the manifest or in the layouts...Thank you

Comment: `(R.id.etTelefono)` where is this in your second xml file

Answer (score 1):

```
numactual = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.etTelefono);
```

In this line in your second Activity you are casting your EditText to a TextView. `etTelefono` is defined as a EditText in your first activity layout, did you want to use `tvNUMERO` or one of the other TextViews in your second xml instead?
You have set your second xml as Content view in your second Activity, thus you can only use the things you defined in your second xml.